# onclick load/run this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a html file which will load/run the following code on clicking button. i had tried this method as below.

```
            <!-- Custom -->
            <div id="custom1">

            </div>
            <script>
                function custom()
                {
                var dummy = '<div id="custom1" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999900; width: 100%; opacity: 0.8; height: 768px; visibility: visible;" ></div>
                <div id="custom1" style="display: block; text-align: center; line-height: normal; visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999910; width: 100%; height: 667px;" ><div id="close_button_div" align="center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 9999930;"></div><div style="background: transparent; height: 768px; z-index: 9999915;">
                    <iframe id="custom1" width="100%" height="768" id="overlay_iframe" src="" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 768px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 9999920; display: block; background-color: transparent;" scrollbars="NO" ></iframe>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id="custom1" align="center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 9999930;" ></div>
                <div id="custom1" style="background: transparent; height: 768px; z-index: 9999915;" >
                    <iframe id="custom1" width="100%" height="768" id="overlay_iframe" src="captcha.php" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 768px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 9999920; display: block; background-color: transparent;" scrollbars="NO">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>';
                document.getElementById('custom1').innerHTML += dummmy;
                }
            </script>
            <!-- END custom-->
```

Here is the code that i used for button onclick

```
<a href="#" onclick="custom();">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Its not working for me.

Comment: Have you heard of `load()` in jQuery

Comment: remove the plus(+) at the end`document.getElementById('custom1').innerHTML = dummmy;`

Comment: lol sorry for this, i figured the error. Its in "dummy", I wrote it as "dummmy" at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove **+** sign before dummy. there is variable name spelling mistake for  **dummmy** in your code.
Here is the working code

```js
 function custom()
                {
                var dummy= '<div id="custom1" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999900; width: 100%; opacity: 0.8; height: 768px; visibility: visible;" ></div> <div id="custom1" style="display: block; text-align: center; line-height: normal; visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999910; width: 100%; height: 667px;" ><div id="close_button_div" align="center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 9999930;"></div><div style="background: transparent; height: 768px; z-index: 9999915;"> <iframe id="custom1" width="100%" height="768" id="overlay_iframe" src="" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 768px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 9999920; display: block; background-color: transparent;" scrollbars="NO" ></iframe>  </div> </div>                <div id="custom1" align="center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 9999930;" ></div>  <div id="custom1" style="background: transparent; height: 768px; z-index: 9999915;" ><iframe id="custom1" width="100%" height="768" id="overlay_iframe" src="captcha.php" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 768px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 9999920; display: block; background-color: transparent;" scrollbars="NO">  </iframe> </div>  </div>';
                document.getElementById('custom1').innerHTML = dummy;
                }
```

```html
 <div id="custom1">
 </div>
 <a href="#" onclick="custom();">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Comment: thank you @Bhavin Solanki i figured it out and in the mean time you answered it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remove **+** after innerHTML.

```
function custom()
{
      var dummy = '<div id="custom1" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999900; width: 100%; opacity: 0.8; height: 768px; visibility: visible;" ></div><div id="custom1" style="display: block; text-align: center; line-height: normal; visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999910; width: 100%; height: 667px;" ><div id="close_button_div" align="center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 9999930;"></div><div style="background: transparent; height: 768px; z-index: 9999915;"><iframe id="custom1" width="100%" height="768" id="overlay_iframe" src="" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 768px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 9999920; display: block; background-color: transparent;" scrollbars="NO" ></iframe></div>
</div><div id="custom1" align="center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 9999930;" ></div><div id="custom1" style="background: transparent; height: 768px; z-index: 9999915;"><iframe id="custom1" width="100%" height="768" id="overlay_iframe" src="captcha.php" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 768px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 9999920; display: block; background-color: transparent;" scrollbars="NO">                 </iframe></div></div>';                    document.getElementById('custom1').innerHTML = dummmy;
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/n70o70tz/

Comment: @harshaaliaschinna, I have added working fiddle demo. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a syntax error do this, try concatenating the individual lines using **`+`** operator.

```
<script>
function custom()
 {
  var dummy = '<div id="custom1" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999900; width: 100%; opacity: 0.8; height: 768px; visibility: visible;" ></div>'+
                '<div id="custom1" style="display: block; text-align: center; line-height: normal; visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999910; width: 100%; height: 667px;" ><div'+ 'id="close_button_div" align="center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 9999930;"></div><div style="background: transparent; height: 768px; z-index: 9999915;">'+
                    '<iframe id="custom1" width="100%" height="768" id="overlay_iframe" src="" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 768px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 9999920; display: block; background-color: transparent;" scrollbars="NO" ></iframe>'+
     '</div></div><div id="custom1" align="center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 9999930;" ></div>'+
                '<div id="custom1" style="background: transparent; height: 768px; z-index: 9999915;" >'+
                    '<iframe id="custom1" width="100%" height="768" id="overlay_iframe" src="captcha.php" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 768px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 9999920; display: block; background-color: transparent;" scrollbars="NO">'+
       '</iframe> </div> </div>';
                document.getElementById('custom1').innerHTML += dummmy;
                }
 </script>
<!-- END custom-->
```